# How can I properly send some data to a parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a checkout page for an eCommerce react website and I'm having trouble sending some data properly to a parent component to display all the numbers correctly.

here's the parent component

```
export default function cart() {
  return (
    <div className='cart-page'>
      <div className='checkout-sidebar'>
        {/*sidebar content*/}
      </div> // this is the sidebar where i want to display the data

      <div className='cart-items-container'> 

        {Products.map((item) => {       //Products is an array of objects representing the products 
        if (cartItems[item.id] !== 0)   //cartItems is an object useState variable with the ID and quantity of the products as the name and value pair 
          return (
            <CartProduct key={item.id} /*other attributes*/></CartProduct> //child component
          )
        }}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
    }
```

And here's the child component

```
  export default function cartProduct({img, name, itemQty , price, id, add, remove, del}) {
  const {checkoutItems, setCheckoutItems} = useContext(ShopContext) //checkoutItems is the array useState variable -  
//I created to hold an array of prices of the products in the cart (quantity adjusted prices)

  let total = price * itemQty //itemQty is the quantity of this specific instance of the product added to the cart
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCheckoutItems(arr => ([...arr, total]))  
  }, [])
  
  return (
    <div className='cart-product-container'>
      {/*product-content*/}
    </div>
  )
}
```

So I'm using useEffect here because when I attempt to simply add this component's price with the `checkoutItems` useState to the array, it starts infinitely updating the array like the component is infinitely rerendering so an explanation on that would be nice...

So in conclusion, I need to add the `total` variable to the array for each component and be able to update it as soon as the quantity changes (which is done by the add, remove, and delete `del` functions imported as props)

Edit*

Just in case, here's some additional context if needed

A sample object data from the Products array of objects I mentioned

```
  {
    id: 1,
    ProductName: 'Beanie',
    ProductPrice: 15,
    ProductImage: product1
  }
```

The remove function for the `CartProduct` component (the mentioned add and del functions work similarly)

```
  const removeFromCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] - 1}));
  };
```

I might have overcomplicated the question but I wanted to be clear. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is a little confusing at the moment. It's difficult to tell whether you're using state or context or both, and what information you're trying to pass to the component. Is it basically: you have a list of items in the `Cart` component (note the capitalised component name btw), and you use `CartProduct` to render each one. And each `CartProduct` has some controls that allow you to add to/remove from/delete the product. And based on the price/count etc you need to maintain a total in `Cart` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a some assumptions with this example based on your question:

1. Only the products that are in the cart are held in the cart state (not the whole shop inventory).
2. You're only using state (and not context).
3. You want to show a grand price total for all products in the `Cart` component, but you also want to show the individual prices for each item.

So in this code:

1. `Cart` holds the state.
2. Each product in state has, in addition to the `id` and `name`, `qty` and `price` properties.
3. There is one handler that deals with all of the button actions.
4. [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) on the buttons allow the handler to identify the product id, and the action the button fires. One handler makes things a lot simpler imo.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// For convenience we're just passing in a list of the products in
// the cart
function Example({ config }) {

  // And we're adding that to the state immediately
  const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(config);

  // The handler listens out for events from the cart
  // products.
  function handleClick(e) {
    
    // It destructures the `type` and `id` from
    // the clicked element's dataset
    const { type, id } = e.target.dataset;
    
    // It makes a copy of the products state
    const copy = [...products];
    
    // It finds the index of the associated product
    const index = copy.findIndex(product => {
      return product.id === +id;
    });

    // If the product exists in the cart
    if (index >= 0) {

      // A switch is used to determine the action
      // to be taken
      switch (type) {

        // If the `qty` is above zero decrement
        // its value in that product
        case 'decrement': {
          if (copy[index].qty > 0) {
            --copy[index].qty;
          }
          break;
        }

        // Increment the value
        case 'increment': {
          ++copy[index].qty;
          break;
        }

        // Remove the product from state completely
        case 'remove': {
          copy.splice(index, 1);
          break;
        }

      }

      // Finally we set the new state
      // with the updated copy
      setProducts(copy);
 
    }
  
  }

  // To get the grand total of all products
  // we `reduce` over the array of products in state
  // and multiply each products qty by price
  function getTotal() {
    return products.reduce((acc, c) => {
      return acc + (c.qty * c.price);
    }, 0);
  }

  // Display the grand total, and `map` over the
  // products in state using the `CartProduct` component
  // to render each one. Note: we pass down a reference
  // to the handler in the component props
  return (
    <section class="cart">
      <p class="total">${getTotal()}</p>
      <hr />
      {products.map(product => {
        return (
          <CartProduct
            key={product.id}
            {...product}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />
        );
      })}
    </section>
  );

}

function CartProduct(props) {

  // Destructure all the properties
  // from the component props       
  const {
    id,
    name,
    qty,
    price,
    handleClick
  } = props;

  // Get the product total
  function getTotal() {
    return qty * price;
  }

  // Display the product name, qty, and total,
  // and also return a series of buttons that do all
  // the actions
  return (
    <section>
      <heading>{name}&nbsp;{qty} - ${getTotal()}</heading>
      <p>
        <button
          class="action"
          data-type="decrement"
          data-id={id}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >-
        </button>
        <button
          class="action"
          data-type="increment"
          data-id={id}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >+
        </button>
        <button
          class="action"
          data-type="remove"
          data-id={id}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >Remove
        </button>
      </p>
    </section>
  );

}

const config = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Carrots', qty: 0, price: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Rhubarb', qty: 0, price: 12 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Meat Tornado', qty: 0, price: 32 }
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button.action:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 0.25em; }
.total { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```