# react javascript event.target/currentTarget undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks, jsx

My problem is that when I open my modal cart where i have cartItems, i press on + sign to increase my cartItem quantity and for the first click i get undefined ([{…}]
0
:
{id: 3, quantity: undefined}
length
:
1[[Prototype]]
: Array(0))

after is set to undefined and i click again i get de incremented value.

I tried e.target.innerText, e.currentTarget.innerText... i remade the whole logic of all functions in this component, i tought it is beacause of useEffect() but everything works fine until i try to increment the value by getting the + or - sign from jsx

```js
import React,{ useEffect, useState } from "react";
import classes from "./Modal.module.css";


export default function Modal({ setModal }) {
    const [cart,setCart] = useState([]);
    const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState([]);
    const [qty,setQty] = useState();
    const [extracted, setExtracted] = useState([])

    console.log(extracted);
    const updateQuantity = (currentId,test) => {
        let element = extracted.filter(x=>x.id == currentId)[0];
        let filteredArray = extracted.filter(x => x!=element);
        console.log("elementtt",element.quantity)
        let newElement = {id:parseInt(currentId),quantity:qty};
        filteredArray.push(newElement);
        setExtracted(filteredArray);
    }

    const updateCartItem = (e) =>{
        // e.preventDefault();
        const currentId = e.currentTarget.id;  
        let test;
        var htmlText = e.currentTarget.dataset;
        console.log("html text",htmlText)
        if(htmlText == "+"){
            setQty(99)
        }else{
            setQty("11111")
        }    
        updateQuantity(currentId,test);
    }
const fetchCart = async () =>{
        const request = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/cart/get-cart")
        const response = await request.json();
        setCart(response);
        setCartItems(response.cartItems)
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetchCart();
    },[])

    useEffect(()=>{
        extract();
    },[cartItems])

    const extract = () =>{
        for(let c of cartItems){
            console.log(c.product.id)
            const newObj = {id:c.product.id, quantity: c.quantity}
            setExtracted(extracted => [...extracted,newObj])
        }
    }
    

    const fetchDeleteItemFromCart = async (e)=>{
          const request = await fetch(`http://localhost:8080/cart/delete-cart-item/${e.target.id}`,{method:'DELETE'})
          const response = await request.json();
          setCart(response);
          setCartItems(response.cartItems);
      }

      function closeModal() {
        setModal(false);
    }
  return (
      <>
      <div className={classes.container}>
          <div className={classes.modalContainer}>
              <>
              <div className={classes.close_container}>
              <h1 className={classes.wrapper}>Shopping Cart</h1>
              <span className={classes.close_btn}>
              <i
                                  className="fas fa-close"
                                  onClick={closeModal
                                  }
                              ></i>
              </span>
              </div>
                      <div className={classes.project}>
                          <div className={classes.shop}>
                          {cartItems && cartItems.map(item=>(
                               <div className={classes.box}>
                                   <img src={item.product.image} alt=""/>
                                   <div className={classes.content}>
                                      <h3>{item.product.productName}</h3>
                                      <h4>{item.product.sellingPrice * item.quantity} $</h4>
                                      <p className={classes.unit}>Quantity:
                                       <button 
                                       onClick={updateQuantity}
                                       id={item.product.id} 
                                       data-sign={"-"}>-</button>
                                       <input
                                       onChange={(e)=> setQty(item.quantity)}
                                       value={item.quantity}/>
                                       <button  
                                       onClick={e=>updateCartItem(e)}
                                       id={item.product.id} 
                                       data-sign={"+"}>+</button></p>
                                      <p className={classes.btnArea}>
                                          <i className="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                          <span className={classes.btn2} id={item.product.id} onClick={fetchDeleteItemFromCart}>Remove</span>
                                      </p>
                                   </div>
                               </div>
                                ))}
                          </div>
                      <div className={classes.rightBar}>
                          <p><span>Subtotal</span> <span>{cart.totalPrices}</span></p>
                          <hr>
                          </hr>
                          <p><span>Tax</span> <span>{cart.totalPrices}</span></p>
                          <hr>
                          </hr>
                          <p><span>Shipping</span> <span>{cart.totalPrices}</span></p>
                          <hr>
                          </hr>
                          <p><span>Total</span> <span>{cart.totalPrices}</span></p>
                          <a href="/order"><i className="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Checkout</a>
                      </div>
                      </div>
              </>
              </div>
      </div>

    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a function called `updateCartItem` that updates the quantity, and a function called `updateQuantity` that does something else? Anyway [I wrote this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74903656/1377002) to another question regarding updating cart items yesterday which might help guide you to a solution. It uses one state which makes things less complicated.

Comment: i tried to brake the code in multiple functions because my first try got one function with many lines

Comment: That's great - and you should do that but look at the functions that your +/- buttons are calling - they're calling `updateQuantity` which is the _wrong_ function. That's where the problem is. Rename your functions with each other. And also change the function your "submit" button is calling too.

Comment: your solution from the above links works perfect even tho its a bit o magic yet, i adapted to my code and its good and also i saved the modified quantities in my DB