# How do I add here handleDecrease,handleIncrease and handleDelete to change the product.quantity amount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, cart, product-quantity

```
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { userRequest } from "../requestMethods";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/DeleteOutlineOutlined';


const Cart = () => {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);
  const history = useHistory();
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const makeRequest = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await userRequest.post("/checkout/payment", {
          amount: cart.total * 100,
       });
        history.push("/success", {
          products: cart,
        });
      } catch { }
    };
    cart.total >= 1 && makeRequest();
    if (cart.total < 1) {

    }
  }, [cart.total, history]);
  const handleQuantity = (type) => {
    if (type === "dec") {
      quantity > 1 && setQuantity(quantity - 1);
    } else {
      setQuantity(quantity + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
            {cart.products.map((product) => (
              <Product>
                <PriceDetail>
                  <ProductAmountContainer>
                    <AddIcon onClick={() => handleQuantity("inc")} />
                    <ProductAmount>{product.quantity}</ProductAmount>
                    <RemoveIcon onClick={() => handleQuantity("dec")} />
                    <DeleteOutlineOutlinedIcon style={{ marginLeft: "10px" }} />
                  </ProductAmountContainer>
                  <ProductPrice>
                    $ {product.price * product.quantity}
                  </ProductPrice>
                </PriceDetail>
              </Product>
            ))}
export default Cart;
```

I need to add:

handleIncrease,

handleDecrease,

handleDelete. Or just i should somehow change handleQuantity function

But i don't inderstand how to do this.  Because my quantity goes from product, so if i'm trying to change it, I am  just changing all itemses amount.

Comment: Based on your current state you can only have one product in the cart at one time. So I would start with what your `cart` state is meant to represent. I'm assuming you want a number of products - so you might consider a `products` state which is an array into which you can add product (objects). You can then increase/decrease the quantity of each product separately, and then increase the _total_ quantity by writing a function to get the products' individual totals.

Comment: I am a newbie, i did it by tutorial.So,sorry for stupid question,but how?

Comment: The question itself isn't stupid but it might be a little broad to be able to break down everything for you. From the tutorial have you understood how JS data structures, Redux, and React state management work, or are you just typing in code hoping something will work? It sounds like you want [to implement something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74903656/1377002) (caveat: SO answer I wrote a while ago)?

Comment: I understand a half , what ytber doing,mostly I don't understand how Register works in api,when i add data from PostMan, it's OK,but when i just type text in inputs(placeholders) i can't just understand how to merge this data to my DataBase.Also how I should add search for components.But anyway ,Thank you!